# history.back() changing entire browser window in JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a JQuery Mobile app and for some reason the history.back() button is now causing the browser window to go back, rather than it going back to the previous JQuery Mobile DOM page.

Has anyone else experienced this, or does anyone have suggestions on where to look?  Unfortunately I can't use data-rel="back" as I need to call the back action programatically.

Note: I'm not ruling out that maybe I changed something to cause this to behave differently.  (I was toying with trying to get paths to show in the browser URL.  Perhaps that conflicts with history.back()? )

Answer (score 0):

I see some other people with this issue at http://forum.jquery.com/topic/trouble-with-history-back-in-jquery-mobile-application, so for now I've implemented my own primitive "back" history system.  If anyone else has experienced this issue, though, I'm open for a proper fix.